# for loop not functioning correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I've gotten into python very recently and I've been experiencing this strange bug on a program I've been writing in my own time.

the program makes a grid of letters in accordance to a list called `all_object_info`, where it stores more lists telling a function named `make_line()` what to do. these sublists contain 3  entries: the first index is for the x value, the second for the y, and the third for what letter is to be put by `make_line()`

the "make_line()" function takes an argument for what y value it is for, then it cycles through the amount of x values as defined by `num_of_xrows` adding an `empty` (also defined by variable) letter to a `line` variable if there are no objects with the same x and y values that it is currently on, and adding the third index of the object if the values do match up.

the issue I've ran into is that the `for` in the function for what ever reason skips over and ends up placing an `empty` where there is meant to be a object, this only seems to happen when two objects are side-by-side of one another where the one to the right is not "rendered".

thus:

```
empty = "░"
num_of_yrows = 10
num_of_xrows = 10

all_object_info = [[2,2,"B"],[1,2,"B"]]


def make_line(row):
    x=0
    y=row
    line=""

    while x <= num_of_xrows:
        for obj in all_object_info:
            if x == obj[0] and row == obj[1]:
                line += obj[2]
                x += 1
        if x <= num_of_xrows:
            line += empty
            x += 1
    return line


def make_grid():
    grid = ""
    num = 0
    while  num <= num_of_yrows:
        grid += make_line(num)+"\n"
        num += 1
    print(grid)

make_grid()
```

would produce:

```
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░B░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
```

when it is meant to produce:

```
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░BB░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
```

strangely, switching the values in `all_object_info` to:
`[[1,2,"B"],[2,2,"B"]]` from `[[2,2,"B"],[1,2,"B"]]`
makes it produce the desired outcome:

```
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░BB░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░░
```

I'm pretty certain that the only thing wrong with the program is with the `make_line()` function, as I've gone over it countless times with a python visualizer to see that the `for` loop was skipping over when it was not meant to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `make_line`, you could potentially increase `x` by 2 in a single iteration of the `while` loop.

That is, look at what happens when `x` is 1.  You'll add a `'B'` to `line` and then increase `x` to 2.  Since the elements of `all_object_info` are out of order, you won't check against the other object again this iteration.

After that, you compare `x` to `num_of_xrows` which is 10.  Since `x` is 2, the `if` block is executed, an `empty` is added to `line`, and `x` is increased to 3.

You therefore skip over the `'B'` which is supposed to be added when `x` is 2.

Instead, try this:

```
def make_line(row):
    x=0
    y=row
    line=""

    while x <= num_of_xrows:
        for obj in all_object_info:
            if x == obj[0] and row == obj[1]:
                line += obj[2]
                break
        else: # That is, if we didn't hit a break.
            if x <= num_of_xrows:
                line += empty
        x += 1
    return line
```

Answer (score 3):

You will skip `x` when you do `x += 1` twice in a for-loop.
Maybe you can try this:

```
def make_line(row):
    x=0
    line=""
    while x <= num_of_xrows:
        is_found =False
        for obj in all_object_info:
            if x == obj[0] and row == obj[1]:
                line += obj[2]
                is_found = True
        if not is_found:
            line += empty
        x += 1
    return line
```